# Why do I get incorrect password error when running bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind

2023-07-24T19:29:18Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:34976
2023-07-24T19:29:18Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:34992
2023-07-24T19:29:23Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:53546
2023-07-24T19:29:23Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:53560
2023-07-24T19:29:23Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:53570
2023-07-24T19:29:24Z Syncing txindex with block chain from height 552401
2023-07-24T19:29:28Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:53572
2023-07-24T19:29:28Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:53584
2023-07-24T19:29:28Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:53596
2023-07-24T19:29:33Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:39826
2023-07-24T19:29:33Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:39828
2023-07-24T19:29:33Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:39836
2023-07-24T19:29:34Z Saw new header hash=0000000000000000000045e3ad3ef1bb4793b9ce8af5c74935d856f2763d160b height=800103
2023-07-24T19:29:38Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:39840
2023-07-24T19:29:38Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:39842
2023-07-24T19:29:38Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:39850
2023-07-24T19:29:39Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000045e3ad3ef1bb4793b9ce8af5c74935d856f2763d160b height=800103 version=0x2cda8000 log2_work=94.319396 tx=869321812 date='2023-07-24T19:28:50Z' progress=1.000000 cache=5.6MiB(38132txo)
2023-07-24T19:29:43Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:53514

Comment: What are you doing? How did you configure things? Presumably, you, or something, is trying to connect with the wrong password.

Comment: I followed ministry of nodes youtube guide to setup bitcoind on ubuntu and these are my configuration settings                                                                                                                              bitcoin.conf settings
server=1
txindex=1
daemon=1
rpcport=8332
rpcbind=0.0.0.0
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcallowip=10.0.0.0/8
rpcallowip=172.0.0.0/8
rpcallowip=192.0.0.0/8
zmqpubrawblock=tcp://0.0.0.0:28332
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://0.0.0.0:28333
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://0.0.0.0:28334
whitelist=127.0.0.1
rpcauth=bitcoin:[output of rpcauth.py]

Comment: proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
listen=1
bind=127.0.0.1
onlynet=onion

Comment: Are you or some software that you are running trying to connect to your node over the RPC interface (e.g. with bitcoin-cli)? The error message means exactly what it says - something tried to connect to it from the given ip and port, and it gave the wrong password.